# The Start Playing option is not displayed when I call Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to learn Google Play Games Services and I'm having trouble with Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent. Is it supposed to display the intent on all users that were invited?

I'm able to display the player selection and after selecting a player, I call

```
Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
```

inside onRoomCreated, and the default waiting room intent is also displayed but only on the device of the player that created the room. But after that I don't receive anything from any of the callbacks.

Here's my code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textViewMessages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMessages);

    buttonStartMatch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartMatch);
    buttonStartMatch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.buttonStartMatch:
                    Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getSelectOpponentsIntent(mGoogleApiClient, 1, 7, true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_OPPONENT);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    // Create the Google Api Client with access to the Play Games services
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i("RC_SIGN_IN", "OK");
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                Log.i("RC_SIGN_IN", "FAILED");
            }
            break;
        case RC_RESOLVE_ERROR:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i("RC_RESOLVE_ERROR", "OK");
                textView.setText("");
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            else {
                Log.i("RC_RESOLVE_ERROR", "FAILED");
            }
            break;
        case RC_SELECT_OPPONENT:
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // user canceled
                return;
            }

            // get the invitee list
            final ArrayList<String> invitees =
                    data.getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);

            // get auto-match criteria
            Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
            int minAutoMatchPlayers =
                    data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
            int maxAutoMatchPlayers =
                    data.getIntExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);

            if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
                autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                        minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
            } else {
                autoMatchCriteria = null;
            }

            // create the room and specify a variant if appropriate
            RoomConfig.Builder roomConfigBuilder = makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder();
            roomConfigBuilder.addPlayersToInvite(invitees);
            if (autoMatchCriteria != null) {
                roomConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
            }
            RoomConfig roomConfig = roomConfigBuilder.build();
            Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, roomConfig);

            // prevent screen from sleeping during handshake
          getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

            break;

        case RC_WAITING_ROOM:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i("RC_WAITING_ROOM", "START GAME!!!!");
            }
            else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.i("RC_WAITING_ROOM", "USER CANCELLED");
            }
            else if (resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
                Log.i("RC_WAITING_ROOM", "USER LEFT THE ROOM");
            }
            break;
    }
}











// create a RoomConfigBuilder that's appropriate for your implementation
private RoomConfig.Builder makeBasicRoomConfigBuilder() {
    return RoomConfig.builder(new OnRoomUpdateListener())
            .setMessageReceivedListener(new OnMessageReceivedListener())
            .setRoomStatusUpdateListener(new OnRoomStatusUpdateListener());
}






private class OnRoomUpdateListener implements RoomUpdateListener {
    @Override
    public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {
        Log.i("ROOM CREATED", room.toString());
        if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            Log.i("ROOM CREATED ERROR", statusCode + "");
        }

        Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onJoinedRoom(int statusCode, Room room) {
        Log.i("JOINED ROOM", "JOINED ROOM");
        if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            Log.i("JOINED ROOM ERROR", statusCode + "");
        }

        Intent intent = Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.getWaitingRoomIntent(mGoogleApiClient, room, 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLeftRoom(int statusCode, String s) {
        Log.i("LEFT ROOM", "LEFT ROOM");
        if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            Log.i("LEFT ROOM ERROR", statusCode + "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoomConnected(int statusCode, Room room) {
        Log.i("ROOM CONNECTED", "ROOM CONNECTED");
        if (statusCode != GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK) {
            Log.i("ROOM CONNECTED ERROR", statusCode + "");
        }
    }
}






private class OnRoomStatusUpdateListener implements RoomStatusUpdateListener {

    @Override
    public void onRoomConnecting(Room room) {
        Log.i("ROOM CONNECTING", "ROOM CONNECTING");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRoomAutoMatching(Room room) {
        Log.i("AUTO MATCHING", "AUTO MATCHING");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerInvitedToRoom(Room room, List<String> list) {
        Log.i("PEER INVITED", "PEER INVITED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerDeclined(Room room, List<String> list) {
        Log.i("PEER DECLINED", "PEER DECLINED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerJoined(Room room, List<String> list) {
        Log.i("PEER JOINED", "PEER JOINED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerLeft(Room room, List<String> list) {
        Log.i("PEER LEFT", "PEER LEFT");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectedToRoom(Room room) {
        Log.i("CONNECTED TO ROOM", "CONNECTED TO ROOM");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnectedFromRoom(Room room) {
        Log.i("DISCONNECTED FROM ROOM", "DISCONNECTED FROM ROOM");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeersConnected(Room room, List<String> list) {
        Log.i("PEERS CONNECTED", "PEERS CONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeersDisconnected(Room room, List<String> list) {
        Log.i("PEERS DISCONNECTED", "PEERS DISCONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onP2PConnected(String s) {
        Log.i("P2P CONNECTED", "P2P CONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onP2PDisconnected(String s) {
        Log.i("P2P DISCONNECTED", "P2P DISCONNECTED");
    }
}





private class OnMessageReceivedListener implements RealTimeMessageReceivedListener {

    @Override
    public void onRealTimeMessageReceived(RealTimeMessage realTimeMessage) {
        Log.i("REAL TIME MESSAGE", realTimeMessage.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Optional: Adding a waiting room UI](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui),

> The second parameter in `getWaitingRoomIntent()` indicates the number of players that must be connected in the room before the **Start playing** option is displayed. In the example, we specify `MAX_VALUE` which indicates that the **Start playing option is never displayed**. Instead, the waiting room UI automatically exits when all players are connected.

More information and sample codes can be found in [Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#optional_adding_a_waiting_room_ui) and going through [RealTimeMultiplayer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer) will be helpful too.

Comment: From which callback will I know If there is an invitation for me?